# Ошибка памяти

Tags: c++

При запуске ./a.out выдает чудовищное сообщение:

> `*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x08049ff4 ***`
> `======= Backtrace: =========`
> `/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6c501)[0x42e501]`
> `/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6dd70)[0x42fd70]`
> `/lib/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0x432e5d]`
> `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdlPv+0x21)[0xc36441]`
> `/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6(_ZdaPv+0x1d)[0xc3649d]`
> `./a.out[0x8048801]`
> `./a.out[0x804864d]`
> `/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x3d8ce7]`
> `./a.out[0x8048501]`
> `======= Memory map: ========`
> `003c2000-00519000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 261168     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so`
> `00519000-0051a000 ---p 00157000 08:05 261168     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so`
> `0051a000-0051c000 r--p 00157000 08:05 261168     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so`
> `0051c000-0051d000 rw-p 00159000 08:05 261168     /lib/libc-2.12.1.so`
> `0051d000-00520000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0` 
> `005a6000-005c2000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 261144     /lib/ld-2.12.1.so`
> `005c2000-005c3000 r--p 0001b000 08:05 261144     /lib/ld-2.12.1.so` 
> v005c3000-005c4000 rw-p 0001c000 08:05 261144     /lib/ld-2.12.1.so`006a4000-006a5000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]v0087d000-00897000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 261202     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
>
> 00897000-00898000 r--p 00019000 08:05 261202     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
>
> 00898000-00899000 rw-p 0001a000 08:05 261202     /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
>
> 00b8c000-00c6b000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 396181     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
>
> 00c6b000-00c6f000 r--p 000de000 08:05 396181     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
>
> 00c6f000-00c70000 rw-p 000e2000 08:05 396181     /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14
>
> 00c70000-00c77000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>
> 00f84000-00fa8000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 261217     /lib/libm-2.12.1.so
>
> 00fa8000-00fa9000 r--p 00023000 08:05 261217     /lib/libm-2.12.1.so
>
> 00fa9000-00faa000 rw-p 00024000 08:05 261217     /lib/libm-2.12.1.so
>
> 08048000-08049000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 131889     /home/mr_bunch/a.out
>
> 08049000-0804a000 r--p 00000000 08:05 131889     /home/mr_bunch/a.out
>
> 0804a000-0804b000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 131889     /home/mr_bunch/a.out
>
> 0832d000-0834e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
>
> b7700000-b7721000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>
> b7721000-b7800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
>
> b7835000-b7838000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
>
> b7845000-b7847000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
> bfee1000-bff02000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]`

`Аварийный останов.
Вот код:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cstring>

class Vectorn {
protected:
    int dim;
    double *X;
public:
     Vectorn() {
        dim = 0;
        X = NULL;
    };
    Vectorn(int _dim) {
        dim = _dim;
        X = new double[dim];
    };
    Vectorn(int _dim, double *_X) {
        dim = _dim;
        X = new double[dim];
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
            X[i] = _X[i];
    };
    Vectorn(const Vectorn & _C) {
        dim = _C.dim;
        X = new double[dim];
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
            X[i] = _C.X[i];
    };
    ~Vectorn() {
        dim = 0;
        if (X)
            delete[]X;
        X = NULL;
    };
    int operator ==(Vectorn C) {
        if (dim != C.dim)
            return 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
            if (X[i] != C.X[i])
                return 0;
        return 1;
    }

    Vectorn operator =(Vectorn C) {
        if (C == *(this)) {
            return *(this);
        };
        int i;
        if (dim < C.dim) {
            for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
                X[i] = C.X[i];
            };
        } else {
            for (i = 0; i < C.dim; i++) {
                X[i] = C.X[i];
            };
        };
    };

    Vectorn operator +=(Vectorn C) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
            X[i] += C.X[i];
        return *this;
    };
    Vectorn operator -=(Vectorn C) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
            X[i] -= C.X[i];
        return *this;
    };
    Vectorn operator *=(double n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
            X[i] *= n;
        return *this;
    };

    void Print() {
        printf("Vector(");
        for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
            printf("%+lf_", X[i]);
        printf(")\n");
    };

};

int main()
{
    double g[4] = { 7., 5., 8., 0. };
    Vectorn C(4);
    Vectorn D(4, g);
    C = D;
    C.Print();
    D.Print();

}`

Comment: Окей, и в чём проблема? Никто не будет ковыряться в твоём коде.

Comment: отлично, все заработало, всем спасибо


Comment: Да пожалуйста... Хотя можно было и выбрать "правильный" ответ - так сказать + в репу отвечавшему... Все-таки тратили свое время...
С уважением,
gote

Answer (score 1):

Как минимум ошибка в реализации оператора =
Вы забыли ретурны, соответственно, возвращается неизвестно что...

Судя по выданному сообщению, и по моему трассированию, ошибка именно в этом методе...

Вообще-говоря согласно ВАШЕМУ коду, при вызове метода operator= создается НОВЫЙ объект класса Vectorn и при ЕГО удалении и возникает ошибка.

На мой взгляд, правильнее использовать синтаксис типа

CVector3& operator=(CVector3 &t)
{
...
return *this;
}

то есть возвращать не объект, а ссылку на объект.. И, соответственно поправить другие операторы.

Обновление - поправил передачу параметра - "по ссылке"...

Answer (score 1):

> На мой взгляд, правильнее использовать синтаксис типа
>
> CVector3& operator=(CVector3 t) { ... return *this; }
>
> то есть возвращать не объект, а ссылку на объект.. И, соответственно поправить другие операторы

Ну и принимать объекты по ссылке

> CVector3& operator=(const CVector3& rhs) { ... return *this; }

Comment: 100% - не доглядел :)

Answer (score 0):

Сообщение об ошибке

> free(): invalid pointer

говорит о том, что с высокой вероятностью вы

1. либо удаляете память, которую еще не выделяли;
2. либо удаляете память, которую уже удаляли.

Видимо код

```
if (X)
    delete[]X;
X = NULL;
```

отрабатывает не так, как вы задумали. Попробуйте отловить ошибку печатями или с помощью valgrind.

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется, что проблема с библиотеками, так как у меня все работает, в результате получаем:

```
Vector(+7.000000_+5.000000_+8.000000_+0.000000_)
Vector(+7.000000_+5.000000_+8.000000_+0.000000_)
```

И у вас по-моему пропущен return в Vectorn operator =(Vectorn C).